# Autofilling existing logged in Expresso Store customer information in checkout fields

Tags: expresso-store, expresso, users

Is there some way that when an existing customer is logged in and places something in their cart, that it would autofill their billing information from their existing data, instead of having to re-fill in that information?

Answer (score 2):

My billing/shipping fields are coded like this and the info is autofilled:

```
<div class="field {if error:billing_phone}error{/if}">
    <label for="billing_phone">Phone *</label>
    <div class="controls">
        {field:billing_phone}
        {error:billing_phone}
    </div>
</div>
```

OR, as per the [**Checkout Tag "Billing Details" docs**](https://exp-resso.com/docs/checkout_tag.html#billing_details), you can code like this:

```
<input type="text" name="billing_name" value="{billing_name}" />
```

Comment: Anna's answer is spot on the only thing that I would add is that you need to goto Store > Settings > Order Fields and map the checkout fields to either custom member fields or channel fields if you are using ZooVisitor.

Comment: Also you must empty your cart to reset your sessions if you make template changes and are not seeing the previously stored data properly in your templates.

Comment: I see what the issue was.  I thought Expression Engine already had those fields for members.  I didn't realize I needed to create them.  Now that I've created the specific member fields, and mapped them to the Expresso Store fields, it is auto filling.

Comment: Ah, indeed they must be manually created!